# Relay QueryRenderer does not return expected props from query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I'm attempting to use a QueryRenderer with an accompanying fragment that I intend to use for pagination, in combination with Relay's `createPaginationContainer` higher-order component.

I am using a fragment within the query I'm passing to QueryRenderer. E.g

```
  <QueryRenderer
    environment={environment}
    query={
      graphql`
        query MyComponentQuery($count: Int!, $cursor: String) {
          ...MyComponent_students @arguments(count: $count, cursor: $cursor)
        }
      `
    }
    variables={{count: 10}}
    render={(p) => {
      console.log('render of QueryRenderer');
      console.log(p);
      return (<MyComponent {...p.props} error={p.error} />);
    }}/>
```

This query is performed successfully - I can see in the network tab that the expected JSON is returned from the server as a result of executing this GraphQL query.

However, I am entirely unable to see the result of the query within the context of the QueryRenderer's `query` prop (note the logging in the snippet above). Here's the output of `console.log(p)`.

```
{…}​
  error: null​
  props: {…}​​
    __fragments: {…}​​​
      MyComponent_students: {…}​​​​
        count: 10​​​​
        cursor: null​​​​
        <prototype>: Object { … }​​​
      <prototype>: Object { … }
  ​​  __id: "client:root"
​​    <prototype>: Object { … }​
  retry: function retry()​
  <prototype>: Object { … }
```

This then prevents me from passing the result of the query down to the paginationContainer (in this instance it's `MyComponent`).

Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed?

For reference, the fragment `MyComponent_students` is defined as:

`fragment MyComponent_students on Query
        @argumentDefinitions(
            count: {type: "Int", defaultValue: 10}
            cursor: {type: "String"}
        ) {
        students(
            first: $count
            after: $cursor
        ) @connection(key: "MyComponent_students") {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    createdAt
                }
            }
        }
      }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need explicitly name props in `QueryRenderer` when you use `createPaginationContainer`

```
return (<MyComponent xxxx={p.props} error={p.error} />);
```

instead of

```
return (<MyComponent {...p.props} error={p.error} />);
```

see example https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/8ef8d2615d5294bf94dfeae4e6b0db574150f7f1/todo/js/app.js#L67

Comment: I was able to get this working as per the approach you've mentioned - the only confusing thing was when inspecting the props, I'm unable to actually see the JSON response. Are you able to shed any light as to why this is, and where the container is then able to get the query response from?

Comment: It's because `relay` encapsulate data by fragments ( see http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/thinking-in-relay#data-masking ). You can see data only if  they are included in current component fragment